# Is it a good idea to use js decorators in node.js (express.js) backend project?

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are implementing permission system in our backend project. We need it to be very robust and open for future changes. We also want it to be route specific.
For example: for two different routes /lessons/{id} and /lessons we want to be able to set different permissions. Even more specific, for each route we want to be able to add permission on request type level.
For example: route /lessons GET should have one set of permissions and route /lessons POST should have some other set of permissions.

If we could use decorators it would make the permission system very clean and clear. Before each router function you put decorator with arguments who can access that route.

We searched for javascript decorators and found that they are not natively supported. There are some libraries but they don't seem to be well supported and we got an impression that it shouldn't be used in production environment.

```
@allowedRoles('ragular_user')
router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  await database...
```

If standard decorators are not possible or not recommended for using what else can accomplish the same result?
We would like to avoid long and complicated json config file for middleware that will check who can access what.

Comment: Just write `router.get('/', allowedRoles('ragular_user', async function(req, res) { … }))`

Comment: Yes we thought about using that as the best alternative. We are just looking around to see if there are some cleaner options. We will probably end up with this kind of implementation.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: We used middleware just as Bergi suggested. I wouldn't use something that is not natively supported in production environment. To conclude, I think that this is the best solution, and that it is not that much different then just using decorator one line above.